# Sort an array of objects by a given property order

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I have this array  :

```
displayedColumns = ['CompanyName','Ticker', 'Id', 'Name', 'ActualTradeDate', 
  'Spot', 'PreviousTradeDate', 'PreviousSpot', 'FPrice', 'Status']
```

and an array of objects with the above values as properties :

```
data : [{Ticker : ".. " ......... Status : "... " } , .... {...} ]
```

but the properties in the data array are not sorted in the 'displayedColums' order (as wanted )

the end wanted result is :

```
data = [{  CompanyName : ".. " Ticker : ".."......Status : ".." },
{  CompanyName : ".. " Ticker : ".."......Status : ".." },....
{  CompanyName : ".. " Ticker : ".."......Status : ".." }]
```

**just to be clear, I am not looking to sort the array by asc/desc values of a certain property. I want to change the order of the properties in the array to 'displayedColumn' order

I am not sure how to sort an array  by property order.
thanks a lot

Comment: Please share some sample input and expected output.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your question, you want to sort an array of objects by an object property. That question has been repeatedly asked and answered, so I've closed your question as a duplicate of those. If that's **not** what you're asking, please update the question with a clear statement of what you want to do, along with sample input and output, and we can reopen the question.

Comment: added a comment

Comment: the properties of an object has not order (you neend't anyway) If you want to order by property, google is our friend

Answer (score 1):

Objects are never sorted, but arrays are. Therefore you could turn your array of objects into an array of arrays, containing the objects values in `displayedColumns` order:

```
 const result = data.map(obj => displayedColumns.map(key => obj[key]));
```

Comment: More accurately, object properties are sorted *chronologically*, i.e. things added to the object first will be first

Comment: @jonny in practice but thats not in the specs afaik

Comment: I see, I suppose it's safe to assume an object will never be sorted anyway, conceptually